# Updating a new column from another table: too slow

Tags: mysql

I have a pretty big table and decided to decrease its size by introducing a new column with ID from another table and deleting two other columns. Here are the tables:

```
Table tests:
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20) unsigned  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ml            | varchar(16)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| test_num      | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
........                                                                                                                   

Table data:
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | bigint(20) unsigned  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| test_id   | bigint(20) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |                                                                                                                   
| ml        | varchar(16)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |                                                                                                                   
| test_num  | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |                                                                                                                   
........
```

So I added new column `test_id` in the table `data` and want to fill it with `id` from `tests` and then drop columns `ml` and `test_num`.

I've tried to do it using `join`:

```
update data join tests 
    on data.ml=tests.ml 
    and data.test_num=tests.test_num 
    set test_id=tests.id;
```

This query worked for three hours, so I've cancelled it and tried another:

```
update data 
    set test_id=
    (select id from tests 
    where data.ml=tests.ml 
    and data.test_num=tests.test_num);
```

It is performing for four hours, and I don't know if it will finish in the foreseeable time. My question is: are these queries correct, which is more effective, and are there other approaches to do what I need?

Comment: Try to add indexes on `data (ml, test_num)` and on `tests (ml, test_num, id)`.

Comment: *"My question is: are these queries correct, which is more effective?"* The first query can't be optimized because it needs to scan the complete tables or indexes annyway because there isn't a filter, in best case adding a index would cause MySQL into scanning the index file instead off the table file which is in most cases is faster because in 99% of the cases the index file is smaller then the table file.

Comment: ... The second query is even more worse because its co-related which more or less runs like two nested loops without indexes.. *"are there other approaches to do what I need?"* For better answers see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.. Also questions about performance should include a `EXPLAIN query` for every query involved in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is slow because you do not have index on column you are using in join, Presuming that you have a very large quantum of data.

```
Alter Table tests ADD INDEX idx_ml(ml),ADD INDEX idx_test_num(test_num);
Alter Table data ADD INDEX idx_ml(ml),ADD INDEX idx_test_num(test_num);
```

Try to add the index as it also decrease the execution time of you future queries.

Comment: *"Try to add the index as it also decrease the execution time of you future queries."* If MySQL optimizer is using the index that is, adding a index does not mean MySQL has to use or will use it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Agreed, in some case only where Mysql will not use INDEX. In That case we can see the execution plan of mysql. If the execution plan say that it is not using index. We can force it use the index `FORCE INDEX ( test_num ) `. I know it is UGLY solution, But only one work around i know. If you could enlighten me with a better solution, Thank you.

Comment: A better solution would be to create the correct index... There is only one needed, as you are only filtering on data. And since you are filtering on more than one column, you need to create the index with all the columns being filtered on. `ALTER TABLE data ADD INDEX idx_ml_test_num(ml,test_num);`